# Connecting to Macbook from local network fails

Tags: macos, connection, webserver, ping

I want to set up a web server on my macbook (192.168.0.10) accessible from my iPhone (192.168.0.11).
Both device are on the same network.

- The apache server is running on the macbook and accessible locally via http://192.168.0.10
- The iPhone cannot access this page
- The macbook can ping the iPhone and the router
- The iPhone can ping the router but not the macbook
- The firewall on the macbook is off

I don't understand why all connection are not working to the mac. Is there something else than  the firewall blocking these connections?

EDIT: I test on another local network to connect with another PC and it didn't work neither.

EDIT2: I'm using SecureClient on this machine to connect to my company VPN.

Comment: Can you telnet from one to the other?  Being able to ping the machine doesn't mean that port 80 (Apache's default port) is available.  Try it with `telnet <hostname> 80`; this does not have to be from the iPhone.  Just use another machine on the network.

Comment: It sounds a lot like the devices are *not* on the same network. Is one maybe connected wirelessly and the other not?

Comment: IF you MacBook is connected to your router via cable and the iPhone connects wirelessly, its likely (better: it may be) your router isolates your wifi from other machines in your network.

Comment: I tried to telnet with the iphone but it doesn't work and doesn't have other device to test. Both are connected via wifi. I tested with two different wifi router: the one from my provider and timecapsule.

Comment: Does it work in the other direction? Do other sharing services (e.g. windows file sharing) work in either direction? Does the ping work from the other machine? Is there anything interesting in the logs accessible via `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SecureClient VPN tool was blocking external adress to my mac. I just disable by clicking the SecureClient icon > *Tools > Disable Security Policy*

Comment: You didn't consider *having an active VPN connection* as being relevant to troubleshooting networking issues?

Comment: The problem occured all the time even if the connection wasn't active.  That's why I didn't tilt. Thank you for you help!